# Suggestions on speeding up hard drive backup code

Tags: c#, file-io

I have the following hard drive backup code that compares the .LastWriteTime() time of each file before copying and it is running slower than I expected.  My assumption is that it should run pretty fast (on the order of a few minutes) if there are no files to update. I'm finding that it is still taking over an hour for 210 GB via USB3.0.  I'm wondering if there are any unnecessary, time-consuming parts of my code that I can improve.  I was also thinking about putting each directorycopy() call on a different thread (at least for the first level of directories, but was unsure if that was bad practice).

The code is mostly borrowed from:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-copy-directories

I made changes to ignore the $Recycle Bin folder, log the files that have changed or had issues such as long filenames and being deliberate in how the Exceptions were handled. But most importantly, I added a check to see which file is newer before copying.

```
    private void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
    {
        // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
        if (sourceDirName.Contains("$")) // avoids $Recycle Bin
            return;

        if (!dir.Exists)
        {
            textb_Status.AppendText("Issue with " + dir.FullName + " This folder will not be compied.");
            return;
            //throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
               // "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
              //  + sourceDirName);
        }

        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
        // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it.
        if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
        }

        // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
            try
            {
                file.CopyTo(temppath);
            }
            catch (PathTooLongException)
            {
                textb_Status.AppendText("Filename Too long \n " + file.FullName + "\n");
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                FileInfo sourcefile = new FileInfo(file.FullName);
                FileInfo destFile = new FileInfo(temppath);
                int CompareValue = sourcefile.LastWriteTime.CompareTo(destFile.LastWriteTime); //<0==> Earlier (old)  =0 ==> same  >0 Later (newer)
                //textb_Status.AppendText("CompareValue: " + CompareValue + "\n");
                if (CompareValue > 0) // Represents newer file
                {
                    file.CopyTo(temppath, true);
                    textb_Status.AppendText("Updated: " + file.FullName + "\n");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                textb_Status.AppendText("Issue with " + file.FullName + "\n");
                textb_Status.AppendText("Error Message \n");
                textb_Status.AppendText(ex2.Message + "\n");
            }

        }

        // If copying subdirectories, copy them and their contents to new location.
        if (copySubDirs)
        {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
            {
                string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
                DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm expecting the backup process to be on the order of a few minutes if there are only a few files to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think, it's the amount of data, which slows down the process, but the number of files. The initial file access (check if it exists, get the stats) is pretty expensive, regardless of file size. Furthermore, many people consider using exceptions for control-flow bad style and throwing and catching exceptions may be quite expensive. And from your use case (ie most of the files are unchanged) there are *MANY* exceptions thrown.

Also depending on your disks (SSD or HDD), multithreaded reads and writes may be a very bad idea and slow down the whole process.

And depending on the implementation of `File.Copy()` you may be better off, checking the target first, and only do the `Copy` if it's really necessary. But this is something you can only know after a benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @derpirscher. For each file, I checked if it existed before trying to write. This way, no exception is thrown.  The drive was checked in about 5 seconds!  I modified a few files deep in the source directory to make sure they were being detected and copied. They were.

I had the sense Exceptions were expensive, I just didn't know it was this bad....great lesson!

My code is below. Note: I was receiving errors when trying to get files from my System Volume Information folder, so I started with a check to make sure sourceDirName did not equal that directory.

```
    private void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
    {
        if (sourceDirName.Contains("System Volume Information"))
            return;
        //textb_Status.AppendText("Current Directory: " + sourceDirName +"\n");
        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = null;
        // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
        if (sourceDirName.Contains("$")) // avoids $Recycle Bin
            return;

        if (!dir.Exists)
        {
            textb_Status.AppendText("Issue with " + dir.FullName + " This folder will not be compied.");
            return;
            //throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
            // "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
            //  + sourceDirName);
        }

        {

            dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

            // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it.
            if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
            }

            // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
                try
                {
                    if (File.Exists(temppath)) // Check for newer
                    {
                        FileInfo sourcefile = new FileInfo(file.FullName);
                        FileInfo destFile = new FileInfo(temppath);
                        int CompareValue = sourcefile.LastWriteTime.CompareTo(destFile.LastWriteTime); //<0==> Earlier (old)  =0 ==> same  >0 Later (newer)
                                                                                                       //textb_Status.AppendText("CompareValue: " + CompareValue + "\n");
                        if (CompareValue > 0) // Represents newer file
                        {
                            file.CopyTo(temppath, true);
                            textb_Status.AppendText("********** Updated: " + file.FullName + "********* \n");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(temppath);
                    }

                }
                catch (PathTooLongException)
                {
                    textb_Status.AppendText("Filename Too long \r\n\n " + file.FullName + "\r\n\n");
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    FileInfo sourcefile = new FileInfo(file.FullName);
                    FileInfo destFile = new FileInfo(temppath);
                    int CompareValue = sourcefile.LastWriteTime.CompareTo(destFile.LastWriteTime); //<0==> Earlier (old)  =0 ==> same  >0 Later (newer)
                                                                                                   //textb_Status.AppendText("CompareValue: " + CompareValue + "\n");
                    if (CompareValue > 0) // Represents newer file
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(temppath, true);
                        textb_Status.AppendText("Updated: " + file.FullName + "\n");
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex2)
                {
                    textb_Status.AppendText("Issue with " + file.FullName + "\n");
                    textb_Status.AppendText("Error Message \n");
                    textb_Status.AppendText(ex2.Message + "\n\n");
                }
            }


            // If copying subdirectories, copy them and their contents to new location.
            if (copySubDirs)
            {
                foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
                {
                    string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
                    DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please don't forget to upvote and/or accept my answer ... But to be entirely sure, the exception was the reason for the bad performance and not the (aborted) copy operation, you should do a benchmark where you just raise an exception, when the file already exists